# How to change the environment in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, production-environment, test-environments

What I understand about the working of environments in Laravel is that you have different environments for different, well environments. So, if you are running your app locally you could have a `.env.local` file. If you are testing or on production, you could use `.env.testing` or `.env.production`. **(Correct me if I am wrong.)**
By default we get `.env` file that we can edit. But can anybody tell me what is the workflow of changing the environments in Laravel. I tried the documentation but I couldn't get it. Please help me.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When you install Laravel 5.1 you get two files `.env` and `.env.example` 
if you want to work locally you set :

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
```

in prod you set

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
```

An error message in debug mode

[image]

An error message from production mode

[image]

Note: you have two .env files `.env` and `.env.example` .. you can also create another one that you name `.env.production` but keep in mind that in order to get your configuration loaded you must just rename your file to `.env`

**EDIT :** So in case you are still working in local and you need another database for test, you can create another file so in total you have 3 .env files :

```
.env.production
.env.local1
.env.local2
```

whenever you want to switch configuration just rename the desired file to .env

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 9):

The idea of having `.env.local.php`, `.env.production.php` has been deprecated since Laravel 5. Now, in L5, we have single `.env` file, where you store all your environment configuration. To define your environment, you should put `APP_ENV=local` to this file.

Once you deploy your project on production, you would create `.env` file on the server and define `APP_ENV=production`

If you use service like Laravel Forge, it provides you nice simple way of storing your environment data. But that's another story:)

### Edit

to make use of several db connections you might do the following:

in your `config/database.php` file

```
<?php
return array(

'default' => env('DEFAULT_DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

'connections' => array(

    # Our primary database connection
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'host1',
        'database'  => 'database1',
        'username'  => 'user1',
        'password'  => 'pass1'
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),

    # Our secondary database connection
    'another_mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'host2',
        'database'  => 'database2',
        'username'  => 'user2',
        'password'  => 'pass2'
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
),
```

);

And then, in the `.env` file put another key

```
DEFAULT_DB_CONNECTION=another_mysql
```

Of course, this sort of predefines your connection. If you want to be dynamic, you can do the following

```
$users = DB::connection('another_db_connection')->select('users somehow');
```

that way you would get results from your secondary mysql connection, no matter what is set up in your environment

Comment: What if we are still working locally and we need another database configuration for testing. In that case what should we do?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate it. :)

Comment: @HomoSapien I'm sure you have already figured that out by this point :) but anyone looking for the answer -  you now (in Laravel 6 and above) create a brand new `.env.testing` file in the project root that defines your settings specific to the testing environment

Answer (score 0):

Another way to easily switch environment - is to force cache needed `.env` file. For example, I have the following `.env`s on my dev:

- `.env` - for local development
- `.env.testing` - for unit testing
- `.env.staging` - for local testing with staging DBs

To quickly switch `.env` I just run command:
`php artisan config:cache --env=staging`
or with alias:
`art config:cache` - this caches `.env`